# Nginx is showing 400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to establish SSL connection, and I'm getting 400 No required SSL certificate was sent response from the server.

I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-using-cloudflare-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) for it
I tried everything to solve this issue, but it seems that there is something wrong with the Cloudflare certificate because when I disable ssl_verify_client it is working (with security alert).
Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/username/www/exampleproject;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/username/www/exampleproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/www/exampleproject/exampleproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the link you provided. Approx 2/3rd of the way through it describes this exact error and why it has happened. You have configured your proxy to require a client certificate to be presented by the browser but you haven't told your browser it should present a certificate or which one.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847638/how-chrome-browser-know-which-client-certificate-to-prompt-for-a-site for the process for Chrome (IIRC, Firefox works in a similar manner).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix it. I can't find a solution in the document.

Comment: Is Google down again? Install a certificate signed by one of the CAs in your cloudflare.crt file in your browser. If its not the only client certificate available when you connect, your browser will ask you which certificate to use.